# C# RichTextBox text block selection

Tags: c#, selection, richtextbox

Has anyone extended the .NET RichBextBox control to be able to select text by "block selection"? If so, care to share your code?

Comment: A clarification of "block selection" in your situation might get a better answer.

Comment: OK. Currently, when you select text using your mouse, it selects the text line by line.  With block mode, you would be able to select text by column...like if you were selecting a "rectangle" of text from the control.

Comment: But a RichTextBox can have different fonts of different sizes all over the text file.  If you select columns 3-10 on line 1, what should be selected on line 2?  Columns 3-10?  Or the columns that line up with the X,Y,Width of columns 3-10 from line 1?  What if half a character is in that boundary?  Does it get selected?  This isn't a straightforward problem in a RichTextBox control.

Comment: scwagner,

Point taken.  I was thinking more from a character=column point of view. In my case, I'm using a fixed-pitch font with the same font size throughout the document. Sure, if you change the font size in some places, it's not going to look like a perfect rectangle when you select the text but it will never be the case in my senario.

Comment: Hi Lenard,

I found your post while searching for the same capability.  Have you found a solution?  

Thanks,  Bob

Comment: No I didn't. I decided to hold off for now on that capability. I may look at what kek444 suggested but I don't have the time (or desire) to work it out myself. That said, if I do find something in the future, I will share it here.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the only way to do that is with the SendMessage from the API, using [EM_CHARFROMPOS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761566%28VS.85%29.aspx).

You would have to do some rectangle border search/tracking and experiment to find the efficient solution, but that would be the basics.